# R function used to rename columns of a data frames

Tags: r, function, scope, rename

I have a data frame, say acs10. I need to relabel the columns. To do so, I created another data frame, named as labelName with two columns: The first column contains the old column names, and the second column contains names I want to use, like the table below:

| column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- |
| oldLabel1 | newLabel1 |
| oldLabel2 | newLabel2 |

Then, I wrote a for loop to change the column names:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(labelName))){
  names(acs10)[names(acs10) == labelName[i,1]] <- labelName[i,2]}
```

, and it works.

However, when I tried to put the for loop into a function, because I need to rename column names  for other data frames as well, the function failed. The function I wrote looks like below:

```
renameDF <- function(dataF,varName){
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(varName))){
    names(dataF)[names(dataF) == varName[i,1]] <- varName[i,2]
    print(varName[i,1])
    print(varName[i,2])
    print(names(dataF))
  }
   
}

renameDF(acs10, labelName)
```

where dataF is the data frame whose names I need to change, and varName is another data frame where old variable names and new variable names are paired. I used print(names(dataF)) to debug, and the print out suggests that the function works. However, the calling the function does not actually change the column names. I suspect it has something to do with the scope, but I want to know how to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you need to `return` the changed dataframe.

```
renameDF <- function(dataF,varName){
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(varName))){
    names(dataF)[names(dataF) == varName[i,1]] <- varName[i,2]
  }
  return(dataF)
}
```

You can also simplify this and avoid `for` loop by using `match` :

```
renameDF <- function(dataF,varName){
 names(dataF) <- varName[[2]][match(names(dataF), varName[[1]])]
 return(dataF)
}
```

Comment: I did try the return function, but besides simply printing out the data frame, the column names stay the same. This applies to the simplified version (without for loop) suggested by you: just have print out, no actual change. But using the command line outside the function certainly works.

Comment: @yzhao The dataframe does not change inside the function you need to assign the function to a variable. `result <- renameDF(acs10, labelName)` and then check the output of `result`. If you want to change the output of same variable you can do `acs10 <- renameDF(acs10, labelName)`

Comment: Thanks, now everything makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the whole thing in one line.

```
colnames(acs10)[colnames(acs10) %in% labelName$column_1] <- labelName$column_2[match(colnames(acs10)[colnames(acs10) %in% labelName$column_1], labelName$column_1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the column name isn't in the data dictionary, but it's a bit more convoluted:

```
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(~column_1,~column_2,
"oldLabel1",    "newLabel1",
"oldLabel2",    "newLabel2")

d <- tibble(oldLabel1 = NA, oldLabel2 = NA, oldLabel3 = NA)

fun <- function(dat, dict) {
  names(dat) <- sapply(names(dat), function(x) ifelse(x %in% dict$column_1, dict[dict$column_1 == x,]$column_2, x))
  dat
}

fun(d, df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function containing just on line of code.

```
renameDF <- function(df, varName){
  
  
  setNames(df,varName[[2]][pmatch(names(df),varName[[1]])])
  
  
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.